# Constructor is undefined, when it is clearly defined

Tags: java

I am making a program that plots the decay of atoms. Here is my main, which also does the logic. However, I am getting a undefined constructor error, when it is clearly defined in the other class. Why is this happening?

Caution: it isn't notated. Spare me your wrath.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int chance = 6;
        Random r = new Random();
        int num = 40;
        int[] decayed;
        int reps = 25;
        decayed = new int[reps];
        for (int j = 1; j < reps+1; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                int c = r.nextInt(chance);
                if (c == chance - 1) {
                    decayed[j]++;
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("\n Trial: " + j + "\n Number left: " + num
                    + "\n Decayed: " + decayed[j] + "\n\n");
            num = num - decayed[j];

        }
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new Graph(decayed[])); //"Constuctor is undefined for type int" When I am clearly specifying an array.
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And my Graph.class. It is copied from some forum (Credit to Crieg Wood).

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Graph extends JPanel
{
    int PAD = 20;
    boolean drawLine = true;
    boolean drawDots = true;
    int dotRadius = 3;

    // the y coordinates of the points to be drawn; the x coordinates are evenly spaced
    int[] data;
    public Graph(int points[]){ //This is the constructor which specifies type int[].
        for (int i = 0; i<points.length; i++){ //Copies points[] to data[]
            data[i] = points[i];
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        g2.drawLine(PAD, PAD, PAD, h-PAD);
        g2.drawLine(PAD, h-PAD, w-PAD, h-PAD);
        double xScale = (w - 2*PAD) / (data.length + 1);
        double maxValue = 100.0;
        double yScale = (h - 2*PAD) / maxValue;
        // The origin location
        int x0 = PAD;
        int y0 = h-PAD;

        // draw connecting line
        if (drawLine)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length-1; j++)
            {
                int x1 = x0 + (int)(xScale * (j+1));
                int y1 = y0 - (int)(yScale * data[j]);
                int x2 = x0 + (int)(xScale * (j+2));
                int y2 = y0 - (int)(yScale * data[j+1]);
                g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
        }

        // draw the points as little circles in red
        if (drawDots)
        {
            g2.setPaint(Color.red);
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++)
            {
                int x = x0 + (int)(xScale * (j+1));
                int y = y0 - (int)(yScale * data[j]);
                g2.fillOval(x-dotRadius, y-dotRadius, 2*dotRadius, 2*dotRadius);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lose the [] from 'decayed[]'

Comment: Are you really getting an 'undefined' error? You should get a syntax error. It's not the same thing.

Comment: Check http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 8):

The problems here are with the usage of those `[]` brackets.

Try to re-write your call:

```
f.getContentPane().add(new Graph(decayed));
```

Though you were not incorrect, please consider re-writing your constructor to hold to the Java standards and conventions:

```
public Graph(int[] points){   // NOTE: I moved the [] to a the standard position
    for (int i = 0; i<points.length; i++){
        data[i] = points[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: @ theJollySin `[]` are allowed on both the sides, so why are you mentioning in the answer

Comment: @Abu Forgive me for being pedantic, but I have found that following the standards and conventions for a language makes life easier for everyone.

Comment: yeah that's true, but that may make the OP think that the way the OP used it in his solution was wrong. Rather you should have mentioned(clearly pointed out) it as a convention

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is invalid, to refer to your array, simply use the variable name, without the `[]`:

```
f.getContentPane().add(new Graph(decayed));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this `f.getContentPane().add(new Graph(decayed[]));`

with this

`f.getContentPane().add(new Graph(decayed));`

Just use the name of the variable that you have created without that `[]`.

Those `[]` brackets are used only at the time of declaration of the method parameters for arrays and not when calling the method.